# django get_absolute_url on search result

Tags: python, django, url, django-queryset

I am building board web application on Django=1.11 and try to figure out its search query. I have following `url.py`, `models.py`, 'views.py` and structures

structure

```
blog--- blog
     |    |- urls.py
     |    |- setting.py
     |
     |- boards
           |- models.py
           |- views.py
           |- templates
                 |- search.html
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^search/$', boards_views.search_list, name="search"),
url(r'^boards/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', TopicListView.as_view(), name="board_topics"),
url(r'^boards/(?P<pk>\d+)/topics/(?P<topic_pk>\d+)/$',PostListView.as_view(), name="topic_posts"),
```

models.py

```
class Board(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Topic(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, related_name='topics', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    views = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

class Post(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default="")
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, related_name='posts', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("blog:topic_posts", args=[self.id])
```

views.py

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    template_name = 'topic_posts.html'
    paginate_by = 5 

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        session_key = 'viewed_topic_{}'.format(self.topic.pk)
        if not self.request.session.get(session_key, False):
            self.topic.views += 1
            self.topic.save()
            self.request.session[session_key] = True
        kwargs['topic'] = self.topic
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.topic = get_object_or_404(Topic, board__pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'), pk=self.kwargs.get('topic_pk'))
        queryset = self.topic.posts.order_by('created_at')
        return queryset

class TopicListView(ListView):
    model = Topic
    context_object_name = 'topics'
    template_name = 'boards/topics.html'
    paginate_by = 5 

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['board'] = self.board
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.board = get_object_or_404(Board, pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        queryset = self.board.topics.order_by('-last_updated').annotate(replies=Count('postss') - 1)
        return queryset

def search_list(req):
    Post_list = Post.objects.all()
    topic = Topic.objects.all()
    q = req.GET.get('q', '')
    if q:
        post_list = post_list.filter(post__icontains=q)
    context = {
        "filter" : post_list,
        "q" : q,
        "topics": topic,
    }
    return render(req, "search.html", context)
```

search.html

```
{% if q %}
{% for post in filter %}
<a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.topic }}</a>
```

I have search function in my web application and once I conduct search it displays search result. I am trying to insert `link` to each result so that the user can click a link to that post directly. I think `get_absolute_url` can be easy and good solution, but no luck to implement. It throws `NoReverseMatch at /search` and `'blog' is not a registered namespace`. I think namespace is name of my project, and pass `blog` but failed. Then I passed name of my application `board`, and even no namespace but still failed. What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think you need `blog:` in your `return reverse("blog:topic_posts", args=[self.id])`, as you never declared a namespace on your URLs. Note that `namespace` is different from `name` in declaring URLs.

Comment: @BurningCrystals I edited.

Comment: `return reverse("topic_posts", args=[self.id])` this calls `url(r'^boards/(?P<pk>\d+)/topics/(?P<topic_pk>\d+)/$',PostListView.as_view(), name="topic_posts"),` but this url pattern required two arguments

Comment: I wonder why you did add this `(?P<topic_pk>\d+)` in your url named 'topic_posts'?

Comment: @Lemayzeur I edited. I forgot adding another class in `views.py`.  `(?P<topic_pk>\d+)` is related to `PostListView`.

Comment: I posted an answer, try if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your `get_absolute_url`, better to call the url with its name, and provide all arguments with `**kwargs`:

```
self.topic = get_object_or_404(Topic,
    board__pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'), pk=self.kwargs.get('topic_pk'))
```

- `self.topic.pk` because in your url `topic_pk` is for `pk=self.kwargs.get('topic_pk')` as discribed in your views
- `self.topic.board.id` because in urls `?P<pk>\d+` id for `board__pk=self.kwargs.get('pk')` as discribed in your views, so the `pk` must come from **board**

**codes**

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    if self.topic:
        return reverse("topic_posts",
                     kwargs={"topic_pk":self.topic.pk,"pk":self.topic.board.id})
```